# Google Analytics start always new session for every page visited

Tags: google-analytics

After I moved my website to a new server and activated HTTPS the GA data went crazy:

**bounce rate 100%** almost.

I discovered with Google Tag Assistant Extension that every link I navigate in the website, hit starts a **New Session** / **Session Start**.

I found this error:

```
This hit starts a new session, most likely because the client ID changed. This is caused by an improper tracking code implementation.

Meaning: Google Tag Assistant Recordings noticed a new session being started by the hit, possibly because the hit is coming from a new domain.

Action: Be sure you're implementing proper cross-domain tracking on your sites.
```

The website is a single domain, and I haven't changed anything in the default code.

What can it be? Thanks for help

Comment: I gave you a probable answer but it would be interesting to have some screenshots where the problem is highlighted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[UPDATED ANSWER]

I checked on your site recovered from the report you attached in the comment.

The reported problem (*this hit starts a new session...*) is 100% due to the cookie bar. Until you have accepted the cookies, the `_ga` cookie value is not written. So if, for example, you arrive on the website and then refresh the page without accepting, you will be considered 2 users and 2 sessions.

In any case, I have seen that the `clientId` is maintained when an user accept the cookie policy, so the problem for those who arrive on the site, accept cookies and continue, should **not exist**.

Comment: What should I write in the list?

Comment: SOLVED. Once I deactivated the GDPR banner everything worked perfectly. Thank you very much Michele :)